# How to get template function to use back_inserter over inserter when appropriate

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, enable-if

How do I create a function that adds the contents of one collection to another, using `std::back_inserter()` if possible for efficiency? I don't see an obvious trait for `push_back()` and I'm not an expert with `std::enable_if`, but I'm hoping some combination will achieve the effect of the following:

```
// IF HAS_PUSH_BACK:
template<typename CIn, typename COut>
void addAll(CIn && from, COut && to) {
    std::copy(std::begin(from), std::end(from), std::back_inserter(to));
}

// IF ! HAS_PUSH_BACK:
template<typename CIn, typename COut>
void addAll(CIn && from, COut && to) {
    std::copy(std::begin(from), std::end(from), std::inserter(to, to.begin()));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I create a function that adds the contents of one collection to another, using back_inserter if possible for efficiency?

I suppose you can declare a template function that return `std::true_type` when there is `push_back()`

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto hasPushBack (int)
   -> decltype( std::declval<T>().push_back(*(std::declval<T>().begin())),
                std::true_type() );
```

and the fail-back function that return `std::false_type`

```
template <typename>
constexpr std::false_type hasPushBack (long);
```

so you can modify your functions as follows

```
template<typename CIn, typename COut>
typename std::enable_if<true == decltype(hasPushBack<COut>(0))::value>::type
   addAll (CIn && from, COut && to)
 { std::copy(std::begin(from), std::end(from), std::back_inserter(to)); }

template<typename CIn, typename COut>
typename std::enable_if<false == decltype(hasPushBack<COut>(0))::value>::type
   addAll(CIn && from, COut && to)
 { std::copy(std::begin(from), std::end(from), std::inserter(to, to.begin())); }
```

If you can use C++14 or newer, you can also define a template variable with the value

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool hasPushBack_v = decltype(hasPushBack<T>(0))::value;
```

and you can simplify the functions as follows

```
template<typename CIn, typename COut>
std::enable_if_t<true == hasPushBack_v<COut>>
   addAll (CIn && from, COut && to)
 { std::copy(std::begin(from), std::end(from), std::back_inserter(to)); }

template<typename CIn, typename COut>
std::enable_if_t<false == hasPushBack_v<COut>>
   addAll(CIn && from, COut && to)
 { std::copy(std::begin(from), std::end(from), std::inserter(to, to.begin())); }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, from C++14 onward you can also use variable template

```
template <class...> using void_t = void; // (compensate C++14 lack)

template <class T, class = void>
constexpr bool HasPushBack{false};

template <class T>
constexpr bool HasPushBack<T, void_t<
    decltype(std::declval<T>().push_back(std::declval<typename std::decay_t<T>::value_type>()))>
>{true};

template<typename CIn, typename COut, std::enable_if_t< HasPushBack<COut>,bool> = true>
void addAll(CIn && from, COut && to) {
    std::copy(std::begin(from), std::end(from), std::back_inserter(to));
}

template<typename CIn, typename COut, std::enable_if_t<!HasPushBack<COut>,bool> = true>
void addAll(CIn && from, COut && to) {
    std::copy(std::begin(from), std::end(from), std::inserter(to, to.begin()));
}
```

Comment: Nice and funny. Unfortunately `std::void_t` is C++17 (but it's easy substitute it in C++14)

Comment: @max66 - you're right. I added it for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) with the help of [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and [`std::void_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t).

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_push_back : std::false_type {};
template <typename T>
struct has_push_back<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().push_back(std::declval<typename T::value_type>()))>>
    : std::true_type {};

// IF HAS_PUSH_BACK:
template<typename CIn, typename COut>
std::enable_if_t<has_push_back<std::remove_reference_t<COut>>::value> addAll(CIn && from, COut && to) {
    std::copy(std::begin(from), std::end(from), std::back_inserter(to));
}

// IF ! HAS_PUSH_BACK:
template<typename CIn, typename COut>
std::enable_if_t<!has_push_back<std::remove_reference_t<COut>>::value> addAll(CIn && from, COut && to) {
    std::copy(std::begin(from), std::end(from), std::inserter(to, to.begin()));
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SwSXKElCuhtQQud7)